# How to return multiple rows with entity framework, and sequentially reading them on multiple threads

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a time series loaded into SQL Server, which i need to query and then allow multiple tasks to sequentially read the results from my SProc.

From what i have found on google, it seems possible to execute SProc's or LINQ queries/statements. Im currently not familar with LINQ (SProc would be preferred approach). Is there any advantage of one over the other?

How would i access the data in a sequential manner after executing the SProc? Im assuming it SProc would just alter my ObjectContext. If this is the case, would i need each task to keep count of which row it was at and then access each parameter of the ObjectContext with this counter to get the required value?

The SProc code is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DataRetrieval]
    @StartTime      Time(0)     ='00:00:00',
    @EndTime        Time(0)     ='00:00:00',
    @StartDate      Date        ='2012-01-01',
    @EndDate        Date        ='2012-01-01',
    @Location           nchar(6)    ='Scotland'
AS
/*
Author: Hans
Date: 09-01-2013
Purpose: Used to load a large section of data into memory.
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM 
    dbo.Data
WHERE
    LOCATION = @Location
    AND ( Date = @StartDate  AND Time >= @StartTime
               OR Date > @StartDate )
    AND ( Date = @EndDate  AND Time < @EndTime
               OR Date < @EndDate )
ORDER BY
    DATE, TIME
END
```

EDIT for USR
                ...

```
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Data_GetStoredProcedureList";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 10;
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            cancelTask.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Entity rowData = new Entity();
                                rowData.RoutineName = reader["Routine_Name"].ToString();
                                rowData.ParameterName = reader["Parameter_Name"].ToString();
                                rowData.DataType = reader["Data_Type"].ToString();

                                sProcListRetrieval.Results.Add(rowData);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you want each thread to read all rows or reach thread to read a (possibly random) subset of them?

Comment: Hi, i want each thread to sequentially read through all rows that were returned from the SProc. This process, sequentially reading through the rows, will be performed multiple times.

Comment: How many rows are there? Could you buffer them in a `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily buffer a few million objects in memory. Buffer the results of the T-SQL in a `List` and pass that list to your worker threads.

Comment: Could you please expand on how to execute the SProc/buffer the results into a List? +1 for ur help thus far :)

Comment: That depends entirely on how you call the proc. Probably a call to `ToList` is enough. If you post code how you call it at the moment I will look at it.

Comment: ive added the code i used on a previous project to return a list of SProcs before adding the results to a custom object. This only delt with a small number of rows.

Comment: It looks like you already *have* a list and are adding to it. What's wrong with that? Can't you just do it that way?